# I can't add binary in itunnesconect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to send an App in iTunnesConect.
In this moment:
- I add the app in itunesconect.
- have all the information of the form.
- In xcode, i submit my app (no error)

the problem is: In the section "compilation" (in iTunnesConect) say: "send you compilation with Xcode or Application loader", but i did that.
I cant see the "plus" button in "Biulds".

So, what is wrong?

- I check, the version is ok (1.0) in xcode and in iTunnesCoenct.
- I cant re-upload my app from xcode or Application loader, because "the binary was upload before", however, in xcode change my version to 2.0 and Upload again my binary, but happen the same.
- I'm waiting for 5 days, and not yet.

Plz help.
Thanks.

Comment: You're really asking for help on a programming Q&A site, and using "cuz"?

Comment: Wait for a while sometimes they took little time to show your uploaded binary in iTunesconnect.

Comment: Wait for a while a click a plus sign near the section title, top left corner.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the question (for the "cuz", sorry) and yes, i waited enough

Comment: You did reload itunesconnect page, right? :)

Comment: Every day dude... -_-

Comment: Did you look in the Prerelease section to see if your upload is there?

Comment: Yes, I Did, and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved, but I did so many things, and I don't know what thing really worked. BUT... 
This is the thing that I believe was the problem.
I tried to upload the app from another mac ( a Mac book pro), to do that, I had to Revoke my certificate of Distributor (in member center), later, I exported the profile of AppleDeveloper, and imported it in the MacBook pro, later, I had to upload to itunnesconect again. After of that, not showed any error. later (20 secs later) I'll gonna see in mi profile of iTunnesConect, and ready, Now i could check my Build.

I hope this can help yours.
Regards.